Custom Configuration Provider in .NET Worker Not Refreshing Updates from HashiCorp Vault
I have build a custom configuration provider that loads the configuration from Hashicorp vault kv2 secrets engine.
Here is the method in my configuration provider

    private async Task LoadKv2SecretsAsync()
    {
        foreach (Kv2EngineOption kv2EngineOption in _kv2EngineOptions)
        {
            try
            {
                Secret<SecretData> kv2Secret = await _vaultClient.V1.Secrets.KeyValue.V2.ReadSecretAsync(path: kv2EngineOption.Path, mountPoint: kv2EngineOption.MountPoint);

                if (kv2Secret is null || kv2Secret.Data is null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> entry in kv2Secret.Data.Data)
                {
                    Data[entry.Key] = entry.Value.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unable to load Key-Value version 2 (Kv2) configuration from Vault: {ex.Message}", ex);
            }
        }

        OnReload();
    }

I am using a timer to call every hour.
 _ = new Timer(state => LoadDatabaseCredentialsAsync().Wait(), null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromHours(1));

Here is the configuratio i am using in my Worker's program.cs file:
builder.Configuration
        .AddVaultConfiguration(
            new VaultClientSettings(
                "vault.example.com",
                new JWTAuthMethodInfo(
                roleName: "developer",
                                jwt: "",
                                mountPoint: "jwt"
                               )),
            kv2EngineOptions:
            [
                new(path: "app/some", mountPoint: "default"),
            ]
        );

After the initial configuration when i change a certain configuration suppose AmazonS3:BucketName from FirstBucket to SecondBucket.
This doesn't reflect in the current running state of my application. I have to rerun the application.
I am calling OnReload() method after fetching which should update the configurations. This is working with WebApi app.
What can be done?
